# How do you change the link colour

Tags: ckeditor

How in CKEDITOR version 4 do you change the colour of a link and remove the underline please

Answer (score 0):

So you know the onChange event right? Well, this is not CKEditor standard but a trick I would suggest, on the onChange event replace  with your own style like

```
onChange={(event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    if (data.length > 0) {
       var newData = data.replace("<a>", "<a style='color: green;'>");
       editor.setData(newData)
    }
}}
```

Disclaimer: That I did not test but it should work.